# getdate() not working with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So I have a column named `Timestamp` in my database with a default value of `GetDate()`.

Whenever I use Entity Framework to insert a record, `Timestamp` is `null`.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Can you post a trimmed version of the script being sent to SQL? Just the parts that directly reference `Timestamp` or parts of it (For instance there is probably a query parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing type to datetime2.  See this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) for more information.  Also try using Calculated storegeneratedpattern

try changing to datetime2 and then workaround by adding Trigger

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE ASBLAH
  SET YourFieldChangeTime = getdate() 
  WHERE YOURId IN(SELECT AS_ID FROM INSERTED)
```

If you need to read data back of this date you can do this after context.SaveChanges()

```
context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, p);
```

Comment: Changed they type, but I still get the same result.

Comment: The link does not work, however does work without the 67 on the end, however it is just a detail page about the `DateTime2` class, is that what you intended?

Comment: I ended up going with the trigger.  Easier in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

edit your EDM, make the following change:

```
Type="datetime" 
Nullable="false" 
StoreGeneratedPattern ="Computed"

ref:
http://bibby.be/2009/07/entity-framework-sql.html
```

Comment: this is the right way to solve it but be aware that whenever you update the model you have to change this again

Comment: I am not sure when this changed but as of now using EF 6 you do not have to change it after you update the model.  It persists.  I am using VS 2017 15.7.3 -- hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is probably creating an insert statement that includes all fields, with `null` being the value for `Timestamp`, since you did not provide one.

If `null` is allowed for that column, then that is what will be inserted. If `null` is not allowed, then the default value will be used, which will resolve to `GetDate()`.

Does `null` need to be allowed for your table?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "proper value".  Are you suggesting to toggle the allow nulls in SQL?

Comment: @broke: Ah sorry, yes. Proper value is a generic term for a value that can be stored in that field. So in this case allowing nulls makes null a proper value. I will update my answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I turn off allow nulls, nothing gets inserted at all.

Comment: You need to update your models if you updated the database.  Are you using a code first approach or did you generate the models from the database?